# s:textfield alternative in struts2

Tags: javascript, struts2

When I click a button, values has to be displayed. 
The displayed value should not be a textfield. Since I use the s:textfield tag, the textfield tag displays a text box while what I need is just a display portion without any textbox. Is there any way to avoid the editable textbox ?

```
strHtml= '<s:textfield size="5" 
                       name="p.pL['+pNo+'].reg['+cwNo+'].Div" 
                         id="p.pL['+pNo+'].reg['+cwNo+'].Div" />';
td5.innerHTML=strHtml;
```

Comment: Simple text ? Just use `<s:property />` inside a desired HTML tag, like `<span>`, `<div>`, or whatever.

Comment: @AndreaLigios I tried like < s: property value = "P.pL['+pNo+'].reg['+cNo+'].itemName"/> I got this script error document.getElementById("dP.pList["+i+"].rList["+j+"].itemName").value = itemName; is null

Comment: You cant use javascript syntax in struts tags. You can't even mix those, 'cause struts tags are rendered server side, and when javascript is processed (client side), those are already been translated into text or html. Please edit and reshape your question if you want an answer

Comment: @AndreaLigios document.getElementById("dP.pList["+i+"].rList["+j+"].itemName").value = itemName This value is set in script function. That works fine when I try to access via s:textfield. While with s:property value it doesn't work. Any leads ?

Comment: It doesn't make sense, your code can't work

Comment: If the code is working but you make a change and it stops working you should rollback.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the `s:div` as a container and use button to show on click. The following code works:

**Controller**

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class TestAction extends ActionSupport {
    private String myNonEditableValue = "This is a sample value";

    public String getMyNonEditableValue() {
        return this.myNonEditableValue;
    }

    public void setMyNonEditableValue(String myNonEditableValue) {
        this.myNonEditableValue = myNonEditableValue;
    }


    public String execute() throws Exception {
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

**Page**

```
<s:div id="myHiddenContent" cssStyle="display:none;"><s:text name="myNonEditableValue"></s:text></s:div>
<input type="button" value="Click to show" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('myHiddenContent').style.display=''"/>
```

**Rendered Source**

```
<div id="myHiddenContent"


 style="display:none;"

>This is a sample value</div>
    <input type="button" value="Click to show" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('myHiddenContent').style.display=''"/>
```

Comment: Do you know what `<s:text>` tag is for? Why `<s:div>`? What makes `myNonEditableValue` non editable?

Comment: @AleksandrM, I know what it is and if you don't know you can refer https://struts.apache.org/docs/div.html . Just don't think "I" am the only person who knows everything.

Comment: @JamesJithin Is it not possible to give the script value directly inside ? What I need is to get rid of the text field.

Comment: @sahana, if you refer https://struts.apache.org/docs/text.html you will know that s:text does not create an html textarea or input box. It just prints out the content as i18n text.

Comment: Read about `<s:text>` as well. Then you will find out what it is for.

Comment: What's the point of the `<s:div>` tag here? No reason to use an S2 tag to render a simple HTML div.